# Why is .textContent hidden in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is `.textContent` hidden in Javascript even if the `if` statement says `.textContent`? What do I need to add to the code, sothat it is not hidden?

```js
function F1() {

  var xmv = ['1', '2'];

  xm = document.getElementById("xm");
  one = document.getElementById("one");
  two = document.getElementById("two");

  XM = xmv[Math.floor(Math.random() * xmv.length)];
  xm.innerHTML = XM;

  if (xmv === '1') {
    one.textContent = "one";
  }

  if (xmv === '2') {
    two.textContent = "two";
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>

<p>
  <label id="xm"> </label>
  <label id="one"> </label>
  <label id="two"> </label>
</p>
```

Comment: You're comparing an array to a string in your if conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are comparing an array `xmv` with string which is always false. You need to compare `XM` with string instead like:

```js
function F1() {

  var xmv = ['1', '2'];

  xm = document.getElementById("xm");
  one = document.getElementById("one");
  two = document.getElementById("two");

  XM = xmv[Math.floor(Math.random() * xmv.length)];
  xm.innerHTML = XM;
  
  one.textContent = two.textContent = '';
  if (XM === '1') {
    one.textContent = "one";
  }
  else if (XM === '2') {
    two.textContent = "two";
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>

<p>
  <label id="xm"> </label>
  <label id="one"> </label>
  <label id="two"> </label>
</p>
```